# Fatal error: Class 'HTML' not found Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

Why error, I tried using macro

already added

```
"Require": {
"Illuminate / html": "4.2. *"
}
```

then it is also added

```
'Illuminate\html\HtmlServiceProvider'
```

and aliases:

```
'Form' => 'Illuminate\html\FormFacade',
'HTML' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```

but still the same error

My Macro: app / helpers / frontend.php

```
HTML :: macro ('divider', function () {
return "<hr class = \" uk-article-divider \ ">";
});
```

and already loaded:

```
app_path require (). '/ helpers / frontend.php';
```

thanks for help

Comment: Did you run a `composer update`?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use this html package anymore `"Illuminate / html": "4.2. *"`

so now you have to use this package https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html